# Is there a way to enumerate the video devices on a Java ME phone?

Tags: java-me, mmapi, lg

I recently downloaded a [barcode reading application](http://sourceforge.net/projects/readbarj/) for my phone, an LG [KU990i](http://developer.lgmobile.com/lge.mdn.pho.RetrievePhoneInfo.laf?modelName=KU990) (AKA the Viewty) However, there's a problem that renders the application nearly useless: the Viewty has 2 cameras -- the main one, and a secondary camera located on the face of the unit -- and it is the secondary camera that is unfortunately set as the phone's default video capture device. As you can't point the secondary at anything and see what it's pointing at at the same time, it makes it a bit difficult to snap a barcode!

According to the [JSR-135 spec](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/mm/jsr135/javax/microedition/media/Manager.html#live-capture), it is possible to specify a video capture device other than the default... if you know the device name. This does not appear to be documented anywhere on LG's Web site, nor does the JSR-135 spec describe any way of enumerating the devices on a phone... or is there? Failing that, are there any naming conventions for video devices commonly in use that LG might be using?

I've logged a ticket with LG, but as it's an old device, I don't imagine them breaking their backs in getting back to me... I should also point out that this is purely for my own curiosity so no-one here should feel obliged to break their backs either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LG responded to my support ticket. Apparently, it's not possible to access the primary camera on the Viewty from Java, making it pretty much useless for barcode scanning. Answer reproduced here for search engines.

> You support ticket has been answered. Please visit the LG Mobile Developer Network and login to check the answer at [My Page > My Tickets].
>    KU990i default video capture device is the secondary camera
>   Answer :
>   Hi,
>   KU990i have to Two camera module
>   differently.
>
> Main camera using Joran chipset and
>   sub(front camera) using Qualcomm
>   chipset.
>
> Joran chip doesn’t supported JSR135.
>
> Therefore, we couldn’t supported to
>   the JSR135 using for main camera.
>
> (it is H/W limitation)
>
> It was inform to operator already and
>   we remember operator was confirm it.
>
> So that, we only supported sub camera
>   for JSR135.
>
> BR,

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to get list of all available catpure:// urls.

All urls I know:

capture://image,
capture://video
capture://devcam0
capture://devcam1

Source:

http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/bc00e4ce-7df3-4527-962c-d39843a808d0/MIDP_Mobile_Media_API_Support_In_Nokia_Devices_v1_0_en.pdf.html